# Ubuntu: borked my sudoers file, how can I fix it?

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

I was editing my `/etc/sudoers` file and saved it but it has a syntax error in there.  Now I can't `sudo vim /etc/sudoers` because sudo thinks the sudoers file is not valid.

How can I fix this?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/a/73872/5078

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Boot the system into single mode and then edit it.

Comment: Thanks, my Ubuntu is running under Virtualbox.  How do I boot into single user mode?

Comment: http://www.debuntu.org/recover-root-password-single-user-mode-and-grub

Comment: I don't get the grub options at boot time however, it boots straight into Ubuntu...

Comment: Try holding <Ctrl> or something.

Comment: @red basset: As the vm starts press Esc several times that should drop you into grub then select the recovery mode option.

Comment: Thanks guys, Esc did the trick I am back up and running now :)

Answer (score 21):

You should never edit your sudoers file directly. Use `visudo` - it will protect you from these syntax errors in the future.

To recover from this situation, either boot into single-user mode and edit the file or boot off of a livecd and do the same.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering what visudo did differently.  I need to work out now how to boot into single user mode.  My Ubuntu is running under Virtualbox.

Comment: visudo causes you to edit a copy of the sudoers file.  It will only replace the sudoers file if it validates when you save it.  It will use the editor specified by your EDITOR variable, so you can use your prefered editor.  It can also be used in check mode if you edited the file and want to be sure it is still valid.

Answer (score 8):

If you have Docker installed and your user is a member of the `docker` group you can easily get yourself out of this pickle (and some others) without rebooting or what-have-you:

1. `$ docker run -it --rm -v '/etc/:/root/host.etc/' debian bash`
2. `apt-get update && apt-get install [vim|nano|whatever]`
3. `cd ~/host.etc/`
4. Repair the problem files
5. `exit`

Comment: Docker? Have you seen Docker anywhere in the original question?

Comment: As the question doesn't specify *anything* about the asker's environment and it is now 2015, meaning quite a few people have Docker installed, I understand neither your attitude toward me nor your contempt for my contribution.

It is not at all unfathomable that someone else in this situation would have software installed that, as of today, has been starred by 23.5k people on GitHub. If `pkexec` is also for some reason unavailable then this provides an alternate method, without rebooting, that is almost as quick and simple.

Comment: This actually worked for me!  Saved me a 45min drive into the office.  It did not allow me to edit /etc/sudoers, but did allow me to delete a bad file in /etc/sudoers.d that was causing it issue.

Comment: For clarification: pkexec did not work; I kept getting auth errors.  But this docker hack did work.  Now that I think about it (next day), I didn't think to chmod /etc/sudoers, to make it writable first. Maybe that was why I couldn't edit /etc/sudoers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it saved my day (night, actually)!

Answer (score 2):

As noted in this [similar question on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/73872/5078), this may well work without having to reboot into single-user mode:

```
pkexec visudo
```

Comment: This is the by far the easiest way to do it, if it's available.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, if you have the root password, just login with it and set it back the way it was.

chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers

This will avoid you from booting into single-user mode or worst, booting from a livecd.

In my case I couldn't afford to bring the server down.