# Repair a broken sudoers file

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu : borked my sudoers file, how can I fix it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/206610/ubuntu-borked-my-sudoers-file-how-can-i-fix-it)

**Problem description:**

I have broken my **/etc/sudoers** file by making a typo in it. Now I can no longer use any sudo commands as the below error is thrown. Therefore I can't fix my sudoers file and am effectively stuck.

```
$ sudo nano /etc/sudoers
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 39 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 39
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
```

I found few solutions saying I should boot into recovery mode (like the one below) which I would obviously like to avoid.
[Ubuntu : borked my sudoers file, how can I fix it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/206610/ubuntu-borked-my-sudoers-file-how-can-i-fix-it)

**Questions:**

-Are there any other ways to fix it without restarting ubuntu?
-If it is so easy to lock yourself out of sudo when modifying the sudoers file (everybody can do a typo), why isn't the sudoers config read from memory instead of the file directly? There would be a command (e.g. sudo-load) that would make sure the syntax is OK before loading the config into memory thus avoid this sort of problems.

**Solutions:**
There seems to be 2 ways of recovering it:
-if you have the root password you can simply issue a 'su' and then edit the file
-if you don't have the root password you need to restart into single user mode

Comment: [This answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/206610/ubuntu-borked-my-sudoers-file-how-can-i-fix-it/206612#206612) on the question you linked to tells you all you need to know. Even the /etc/sudoers file itself has a comment warning you to always use `visudo` to edit it.

Comment: this is why i now always set a root password immediately after install. Got burnt the same way myself, on a remote machine I had no access to.

Comment: Using `pkexec $EDITOR` is even better, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-a-invalid-etc-sudoers-file-it-throws-out-an-error-and-not-allowi

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nope, you have to reboot, or log in as root if you allow root logins.

This is the reason you should always use `visudo` when you modify the sudoers file. visudo will check the syntax of the sudo file before saving it, protecting you from this specific problem (but not from writing a sudoers file that disallows you from running sudo!)

Note that sudoers is normally setup to not be writable even by root on Ubuntu:

```
-r--r----- 1 root root 556 2010-04-18 15:05 sudoers
```

So you must have changed the access rights on sudoers to modify it with nano. There is a very good reason files are setup like this. If you come across a file that is not writable by root you should think one, two and three times before you change access rights and start editing it.

Comment: My sudoers file has the same permissions (-r--r-----) but still I can edit it when doing sudo nano. I will used visudo from now on. Also another way to fix it if you have the root password is to simply do 'su' then edit the file.

Comment: @user64204 Interesting... My standard editor (emacs) prevents me from editing the file, while vi makes it very clear it is non-writable but lets me bypass. Another reason to ditch nano ;)

Comment: +1 for visudo.  Also, see http://askubuntu.com/a/73872/5078 for info on using `pkexec` for recovery (via PolicyKit).